# How can I get stock option chains using YQL?

Tags: web-services, yql

I am trying to get stock option chains from Yahoo using YQL. I have tried this command in the YQL console:

```
select * from yahoo.finance.options
```

However, I get this error XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<error xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" yahoo:lang="en-US">
    <diagnostics>
        <publiclyCallable>true</publiclyCallable>
    </diagnostics> 
    <description>No definition found for Table yahoo.finance.options</description>
</error>
```

It looks like this table doesn't exist anymore. Does anyone know what the correct table is?

Comment: When I tried your YQL statement in the YQL console I got 'Cannot find required keys in where clause;   expecting required keys: (symbol).'But when I add a where clause 'symbol='GOOG' AND expiration='2010-06'' there is no problem at all.
We are talking about this one, right ? (http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/)

Comment: Yeah, that's the console I'm talking about. I have to us a community table, and that's part of the reason why it wasn't working. I thought yahoo.finance.options was a table that Yahoo managed, but it's actually a community table from datatables.org. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yahoo.finance.options is a community table. To read about community tables check [here](http://www.datatables.org/). From the link I just posted:

> In order to use YQL with the community tables, you must pass in the datatables env file. You can do this on the YQL console as part of a YQL statement, or by passing in a query parameter.

The YQL console to test this can be found [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20%2a%20from%20yahoo.finance.options&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys#h=select%20%2a%20from%20yahoo.finance.options%20where%20symbol=%27GOOG%27)

Comment: I didn't know I could press "show community tables" to get this table. That's why it wasn't working for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You have to provide at least one `where clause` to make this query work. Like this:

```
select * from yahoo.finance.options where  symbol='MMM'
```

or,

```
select * from yahoo.finance.options where  symbol='A'
```

or,

```
select * from yahoo.finance.options where  symbol='YHOO'
```

All the above queries work fine. If you want more specific data then you have to provide more conditions to filter out your desired data out of the whole data.

Comment: Yes, its working fine. I just checked. Go to this page: https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20%2a%20from%20yahoo.finance.options&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys#h=select%20%2a%20from%20yahoo.finance.options%20where%20symbol=%27GOOG%27

and type: select * from yahoo.finance.options where  symbol='YHOO'

and then hit test buttong, you will see the results. All the queries in my answers are working fine.

Comment: I checked also, seems to work... Two question does yahoo limit usage? It only gave me first month, How could i get the next three months either saying 2014-05, 2014-06, 2014-07 or 'next three months'.  As url or uri, what is the string...

Comment: I am not really sure. I did it a long time ago. I have to have a look then.

Answer (score 1):

Something I just figured out today is that you can just use this to get the option data from yahoo

```
https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/options/SPXS?straddle=true
```

Comment: I don't know why someone down voted my answer, but the endpoint I provided in the answer above returns you a JSON, and if you can't process a JOSN, then I think StackOverflow is the wrong website for you

Comment: probably down voted because the question specifically asks for the YQL

Comment: I am upvoting it. Having working alternate solutions should be fine in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Since the middle of 2014 YQL has the problem, so the option chain from yahoo.finance with scraping could be get by the following codes with: [Python](https://github.com/boyank/yahoo_options) and [Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/50455-get-yahoo-option-chain)